# Does the center of any finitely generated associative algebra over a field have finite type?

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, noncommutative-algebra, noncommutative-rings, associative-algebras

Consider the monoid algebra $R:=K\langle x_1,\dots,x_n\rangle$ generated by $n$ letters $x_1,\dots,x_n$ for $n>1$ over field $K$. Equivalently, $R$ is the tensor algebra $T(V)$ on the $n$-dimensional $k$-linear space $V:=\oplus_i{Kx_i}$. Let $I$ be a two-sided ideal of $R$, and $Z(R/I)$ be the center of the quotient algebra $R/I$, i.e. $$Z(R/I)=\{\bar{r}\in R/I:\bar{r}\bar{x}=\bar{x}\bar{r},\;\forall x\in R\}.$$
It is clear that $K\subseteq Z(R/I)$. My question is: Does $Z(R/I)$ have finite type over $K$? Does $Z(R/I)$ have any nontrivial properties? Thanks.

Comment: There are many finitely generated groups $G$ whose center contains a free abelian group of infinite rank. For such a group $G$, the group algebra $KG$ is a finitely generated $K$-algebra but its center is not a finitely generated $K$-algebra, since a finitely commutative algebra cannot contain as a subalgebra an algebra of infinite transcendence degree.

Comment: Thank @YCor for your comment. As finitely generated associative algebras are so complicated, how shall we understand them in general?